# GDPR Data Access Request

Tags: support, status-completed, gdpr

Due to some recent moderators action, I recently noticed that there is more data stored with my account, than I expected.
To verify, what exactly is stored and what is not, I triggered a GDPR data request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request), and received an e-mail, that I can expect to hear back from that by **7 Dec**, which is quite a long time. Furthermore, there was a status link.

However, when clicking on that link, it says:

> Status: We are unable to process your request at this time. If you’d like to follow up, please contact privacy-support@stackoverflow.email and reference the ID above.

This is expressed a bit unclearly to me. Does it mean, "we cannot now, but we will on Dec 7, as announced in the e-mail", or does it mean, "the request will not be processed in the near future (or at all)"?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I've had [basically the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336713/can-a-gdpr-request-take-up-to-a-month-to-process) happen to me. Email them, the data request will be handled.

Comment: @Cerbrus Will try that, thank you

Comment: Makes you wonder why a form requesting it can't be processed but an email making the same request can...

Comment: @Cerberus, does the data include mods comment and side notes? and deleted comments?

Comment: I had brought up a similar point for how they will handle CCPA (California's GDPR if you will) and it is surprisingly no longer available and I never got a response.

Comment: Independently of your GDPR request, you can see most of the information associated with your profile on the site itself. This is essentially what moderators can see for each user, too. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5636775/ctx?tab=activity), and see, e.g., the "Reviews" and "Suggestions" tabs.

Comment: It's a bug, we sometimes get transient failures during processing of routine requests and that isn't reflected correctly in the status message. We're fixing that and I've kicked the job that processes these requests so that it finishes up where it left off

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug. We have a background task that processes routine portability and erasure requests. Occasionally, a job will fail because of things like SQL timeouts because, well, it's churning large amounts of data. Unfortunately, the status message didn't reflect the transient nature of the failure and just assumed the world had ended.

A fix for the status message is in the process of going to production, but I've kicked the job that processes these requests, so you should have received the results of your portability request at this stage.